# Processing multiple files generated from single input

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a data file that is processed by a script to produce multiple output files. Each of these output files is then processed further. Which files are created depends on the contents of the input file, so I can't list them explicitly. I can't quite figure out how to refer to the various files that are generated in a makefile.

Currently, I have something like this:

```
final.out: *.out2
  merge_files final.out $(sort $^)

%.out2: %.out1
  convert_files $?

%.out1: data.in
  extract_data data.in
```

This fails with `No rule to make target '*.out2', needed by 'final.out'`. I assume this is because the .out2 files don't exist yet and therefore the wildcard expression isn't replaced the way I would like it to. I have tried to use the wildcard function but that fails because the list of prerequisites ends up being empty.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Of course, if you can know the names of the data files in advance, put that explicit list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: fixed the list of prerequisites in second pass.

You apparently cannot compute the list of intermediate files before running the `extract_data` command. In this case a solution consists in running make twice. One first time to generate the `*.out1` files and a second time to finish the job. You can use an empty dummy file to mark whether the 
`extract_data` command shall be run again or not:

```
ifeq ($(FIRST_PASS_DONE),)
final.out: .dummy
    $(MAKE) FIRST_PASS_DONE=yes

.dummy: data.in
    extract_data $<
else
OUT1 := $(wildcard *.out1)
OUT2 := $(patsubst %.out1,%.out2,$(OUT1))

final.out: $(OUT2)
    merge_files $@ $(sort $^)

%.out2: %.out1
    convert_files $?
endif
```

Comment: Why make it conditional? Why not just say `final.out: .dummy $(wildcard *.out2)` and do away with the variable?

Comment: Because it can be that on the first run the `*.out2` files do not exist and the expansion of `$(wildcard *.out2)` will be the empty string...

Comment: You could work around that by running a secondary `make` from within that target, though. That would relieve the user from having to understand and remember this requirement.

Comment: This almost works. There is a similar issue with the `*.out2` files because they may not exist until `convert_files` has been run.

Comment: @PeterHumburg: you are right, of course, how can I have missed that? I should have tested. Thanks, I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question is missing some details I would ask immediately if some SW developer would present this makefile for review:

- does `extract_files` provide the list of files?
- does `convert_files` convert one file or multiple? The example seems to imply that it converts multiple.

  - then I have to question the decision to break up extract, convert and merge into separate rules as you will not benefit from parallel build anyway

The following is the approach I would choose. I'm going to use a tar file as an example for an input file that results in multiple output files

- generate a makefile fragment for the sorted list of files

  - use the `tar` option `v` to print files while they are extracted
  - convert each line into a makefile variable assignment
- include the fragment to define `$(DATA_FILES)`

  - if the fragment needs to be regenerated, make will restart after it has generated it
- use static pattern rule for the conversion
- use the converted file list as dependency for the final target

```makefile
.PHONY: all
all: final.out

# extract files and created sorted list of files in $(DATA_FILES)
Makefile.data_files: data.tar
    set -o pipefail; tar xvf $< | sort | sed 's/^/DATA_FILES += /' >$@

DATA_FILES :=
include Makefile.data_files

CONVERTED_FILES := $(DATA_FILES:%.out1=%.out2)

$(CONVERTED_FILES): %.out2: %.out1
    convert_files $< >$@

final.out: $(CONVERTED_FILES)
    merge_files final.out $^
```

---

**UPDATE** if `extract_data` doesn't provide the list of files, you could modify my example like this. But of course that depends on that there are no other files that match `*.out1` in your directory.

```makefile
# extract files and created sorted list of files in $(DATA_FILES)
Makefile.data_files: data.in
    set -o pipefail;   \
    extract_data $< && \
    (ls *.out1 | sort | sed 's/^/DATA_FILES += /') >$@
```